# How can I get results within a range in MySQL, where some fields have letters?

Tags: mysql, sql, range, between

I have the following data in a `sku` column:

```
UX1905
UX1906
UX1907
UX1907a
UX1907b
UX1908
UX1908X
UX1909
UX1910
UX1911
OP778
OP779
OP800
```

I want to create a MySQL query that gets all skus from the range of UX1906-UX1909, including the skus with the characters at the end of them.

Any ideas on how I would do something like this?

Can I use `BETWEEN` with `LIKE` somehow for this?

Comment: without like "where sku between 'UX1906' and 'UX1909'" works just fine in postgresql. Did you try it this way in mysql?

Comment: I'll give it a try in MySQL... I thought for sure there would be issues, but maybe not!

Comment: I have added it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in postgresql and possibly in mysql too.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE sku BETWEEN 'UX1906' AND 'UX1909'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:`SELECT * FROM my_tbl WHERE sku_val between 'UX1906' and 'UX1909'`